# Using sftp to Transfer a Directory?

Tags: directory, recursive, sftp

When I try to use sftp to transfer a directory containing files, I get an error message:

```
skipping non-regular file directory_name
```

The directory contains a couple of files and two subdirectories.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`sftp`, like `cp` and `scp`, requires that when you copy a folder (and its contents, obviously), you have to explicitly tell it you want to transfer the folder recursively with the `-r` option.

So, add `-r` to the command.

Comment: -r after the put command? I am getting a "put: Invalid flag -r" error message message if I do. Adding it to the original sftp command also does not work.

Comment: Add `-r` to the `sftp` command when you're connecting.   `sftp -r user@host`

Comment: @Kevin I am getting the following error "sftp: unknown option --r"

Comment: It looks like the `-r` option was added to OpenSSH `sftp` version 4.7. Go [here](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/sftp.1?query=sftp&sec=1) and you can use the form at the top to see different versions of the man page.

Comment: Beware that there is a [quite long standing bug](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2150) in OpenSSH's SFTP: when copying recursively a directory to a remote server, the directory itself must already exist on the target server otherwise the transfer will fail with a non-explicit error message: `Couldn't canonicalise: No such file or directory`.

Comment: should be something like:
`# sftp user@remote-host`
`#> get -r remote-folder`

Comment: `get -r foldername` does not work, `get: Invalid flag -r`

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: FYI - I am working on a server that has Centos 7 and have noticed that -r is not an option in sftp. Not every version has the same parameters. I have however found rsync to be handy for this purpose. The command scp does have -r available however.

Comment: the -r flag worked for put for me: `put -r 'iTunes'`

Answer (score 33):

I can only suggest, you use `rsync`. It is somewhat of an industry standard, when moving files over secure connections.

```
rsync -alPvz ./source_dir server.com:destination_dir
```

It is what I've been using for years by now.

*(the `-a` option takes care of things like directory recursion)*

Comment: A bit of clarification on the parameters mentioned: `-a` = recursion + keep symbolic links, permissions, modification times, owner, group, special files and device files (the latter requires super-user privileges); `-l` = keep symbolic links (already included in `-a`); `-P` = show progress during the transfer + keep partially transferred files; `-v` = verbose mode (however it seems mandatory when using `-P` to avoid a weird (bug?) `protocol version mismatch` error); `-z` = enable compression of transferred data.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf it seems to be version dependant whether the `-l` switch has to be used or not. I remember older versions didn't include `-l` in `-a`.

Comment: Using rsync is not adviced if you have very large number of files (40000+) as it might run out of memory - *especially* on smaller systems like Raspberry Pi 1-3. The more files you have, the more memory rsync uses (at least prior to version 3.1 - not sure if it's yet fixed in that or newer either), leading to rsync eventually using all system memory.

Answer (score 17):

This works for me:

1) connect via `sftp` to remote host

2) change into the remote directory you wish to copy. (Example: cd Music)

3) change to the local directory you wish to copy stuff to. (Example: lcd Desktop)

4) Issue this command: `get -r *`

Answer (score 10):

You may also be able to use use `scp`. The general format is

```
scp -rp sourceDirName username@server:destDirName
```

`scp` means "secure copy". The flags are

- `-r` recurse into subdirectories
- `-p` preserve modification times

I believe the rest of the items are self-explanatory

Comment: and scp -rp -P <port> .... when using a non-standard port

Comment: I'd also add the `-C` flag for compression (both scp/sftp). btw - scp uses sftp under the hood since OpenSSH 9 - see also https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0

Answer (score 6):

If you question is actually 'how do I use sftp to transfer a directory', then

```
 sftp -r user@server
```

But if you transferring a directory, I might suggest two better options, depending on your needs.  `sftp` requires logging into the remote server in a ssh-like command prompt, but if all you want is the file(s), there are easier and quicker ways.

**Scp**

For a one time transfer, to upload try:

```
 # upload source directory to remote server
 scp -rp source_dir user@server:dest

 #download directory from remote server:
 scp -rp user@server:source_dir dest

 #specifying ssh key:
 scp -rp -i ~/.ssh/key user@server:source_dir dest

 #remote directory has spaces
 scp -rp -i ~/.ssh/key user@server:"source\\ dir" dest
```

**Rsync**

If you plan on syncing the directories on a regular basis, using rsync makes more sense.  It performs deltas between the two directories, saving transfer time and data over the wire.

```
rsync -r -a -v -e ssh --delete source_dir user@server:dest
```

Here is a list of some of the most common rsync options: ([taken from here](https://kyup.com/tutorials/copy-files-rsync-ssh/))

- --delete - delete files that don't exist on sender (system)
- -v - verbose (-vv will provide more detailed information)
- -e "ssh options" - specify the ssh as remote shell
- -a - archive mode - it preserves permissions (owners, groups), times, symbolic links, and devices
- -r - recurse into directories
- -z - compress file data during transfer
- --exclude 'foldername' – excludes the corresponding folder from transfer
- -P – show progress during transfer

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

If `rsync` is not an option, I would next recommend `lftp`:

```
lftp sftp://user@host.com/path/path/
```

To **download** recursively from server use:

```
mirror
```

To **upload** recursively to server use:

```
mirror -R
```

Note that recursion is the default behavior. The `-R` is for *reverse* — to make the `mirror` command upload instead of download. Use `--dry-run` to make sure it's doing what you expect.

To download without recursion use:

```
mirror --no-recursion
```

You have to `cd` into the directories you want to mirror. Works great!

Answer (score 3):

If you can, use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). It's a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystem, available on most modern unices, and works with any SFTP server. This is a remote filesystem: it allows you to manipulate remote files (over the SFTP protocol) with the usual utilities.

```
mkdir /mount/point
sshfs server.example.com:/remote/path /mount/point
ls /mount/point
cp -Rp /mount/point/somedir /local/location
fusemount -d /mount/point
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a kludge but what works for me is to:

1. Use `ssh` to login to the remote machine
2. Use `sftp` from the remote machine to your local machine
3. Then use the `get` command with the `-r` option to move the directory and all of its files.

Comment: get dont work with -r `sftp> get -r data /opt/bin
get: Invalid flag -r`

Answer (score 0):

you can get from the server to your local path by

```
scp -rp user@server:directoryname(full path) .
```

Comment: Does this add any new information to what other answers posted already?

Comment: This seems to be mostly the same as [Using sftp to Transfer a Directory?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/272165)

Answer (score 0):

It's a workaround,

1. You need to connect via `SFTP`.
2. Go to the directory where files reside.(Example: cd [remote
   directory name])
3. If you have many files with the same format, you can use the `get *.[file format]`. Example: If you have many files with .csv format, then use,

```
get *.csv
```

Comment: Welcome to this forum.  Please explain how this answers the  OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need when I was already connected via sftp, and I didn't want to reconnect using -r param because in my case it's a bit annoying. There's a proxy which I have to connect first and then use a 2 factor token.

So, to avoid that, I did the following workaround: I compressed the folder using another ssh session and moved the resulting file on my sftp session.

SSH

```
tar -czvf myfolder.tar.gz myfolder
```

SFTP

```
put myfolder.tar.gz /server-path-name
```

Then, in the server (SSH), I extracted the folder by using:

```
tar -xzvf myfolder.tar.gz
```

If you're transferring a big amount of data, this workaround might be rather useful because it helps reducing the amount of data transferred and thus, the total transfer time.

Comment: I like your answer, as it makes it easier to see the total size, but does require space on the server to create the zip file. alternatively, you can use `-C` for compression with `sftp`, which would also reduce the amount transferred